# complex number -how to compute the absolute value

Tags: calculus

How to compute absolute value of the complex number $(a+bi)/(c+di)$ is it right $(a^2+b^2)/(c^2+d^2)$? is there another way (without use of polar form)?

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $ c-di $, the complex conjugate. Now you have a simpler form to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is nearly right. In fact,

$\left|\frac{a+bi}{c+di}\right|=\frac{|a+bi|}{|c+di|}=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2+d^2}}$

This works because the absolute value function is multiplicative.

Answer (score 2):

Write the fraction $z = \dfrac{a + ib}{c + id}$ in the form $z = p + iq$ (where $p$ and $q$ are the real and imaginary parts of $z$. How would you do this? You can use the complex conjugate of the denominator.

$\dfrac{a + ib}{c + id} = \dfrac{a + ib}{c + id}\times\dfrac{c - id}{c - id} = \dfrac{(ac + bd) + i(bc - ad)}{c^2 + d^2}$

So the real and imaginary parts are $\dfrac{ac + bd}{c^2 + d^2}$ and $\dfrac{bc - ad}{c^2 + d^2}$ respectively.

Thus the modulus of $z$ is

$\begin{align}
|z| & = \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{ac + bd}{c^2 + d^2}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{bc - ad}{c^2 + d^2}\right)^2}\\
& = \dfrac{\sqrt{a^2c^2 + 2abcd + b^2d^2 + b^2c^2 - 2abcd + a^2d^2}}{c^2 + d^2}\\
& = \dfrac{\sqrt{(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2)}}{c^2 + d^2}\\
& = \boxed{\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2 + b^2}{c^2 + d^2}}}
\end{align}$

*Note: If you are allowed to use $|z_1z_2| = |z_1||z_2|$ or even $\overline{z_1z_2} = \bar{z_1}\bar{z_2}$ then you can use the shorter method given by Tony.*